# Specify a Breeze entity default resource name with a parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, breeze

I have an AngularJS app using breeze for data. The back end is OData v4.

I have a `Customer` entity and an `Address` entity defined in my metadata store.

The API defines the default endpoint for `Address` to be `path/api/Customers({id})/Addresses`

I am able to query a particular customer and get his/her address okay by using `$expand`.

However, if I edit or add a new `Address` for that customer (say, customer #42) and then call `entityManager.saveChanges()`,  I need the POST/PATCH request to go to `path/api/Customers(42)/Addresses`.

Is there any way to configure my `Address` entity to accept a parameter in its `defaultResourceName` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options here - one is to call saveChanges and pass in some custom saveOptions -

http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/saving-changes

With this you could use

```
var so = new SaveOptions({ resourceName: entityId + "/Addresses" });
// null = 'all-pending-changes'; saveOptions is the 2nd parameter
myEntityManager.SaveChanges(addressEntities, so );
```

You will probably need to configure this for your needs.

The other possibility is to use breeze.ajaxPost to create a custom saveChanges method on your own on the client.  This is more work intensive but allows you additional customization.